# Can i write req.body.first-name in a post request?

Tags: node.js, express, post

I am using expressjs and I am making a post API. My html tag is.

```
<input type="text" name="first-name">
```

I want a data from this text field and I write.

```
var firstName = req.body.first-name;
```

But I am got the error.

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

How can I write '-' between 'first' and 'last'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember `-` is a token that usually means "subtraction", so no. That's interpreted as this:

```
req.body.first - name
```

Where `name` is presumed to be a variable, which it isn't.

This is why fields are often named with underscores. So you have two options:

```
// If renamed...
req.body.first_name

// Using existing annoying name...
req.body['first-name']
```